# Touch down repeat event does not works

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want my button to change its background image when the user clicks on it twice. For this purpose i am using touchDownRepeat event. However it does not works.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickedRepeatOnPlate), for: .touchDownRepeat)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the Apple's [oficial documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618223-touchdownrepeat) about `.touchDownRepeat` :

> A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is greater than one.

This event will trigger every time the user taps the button more than once, so four taps will trigger the event three times.

To trigger only double taps, you need to create a `UITapGesture` and set 2 on its `numberOfTapsRequired`:

```swift
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clickedRepeatOnPlate))
  tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
  button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

**Edit**

If you need to get the sender button as a function parameter, you can do as follows:

```
 func addDoubleTapEvent() {
   let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clickedRepeatOnPlate(gesture:)))
   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
   button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)  
 }

 @objc func clickedRepeatOnPlate(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     guard let button = gesture.view as? UIButton else { return }
     print(button.titleLabel?.text)
 }
```

Output

`Optional("button")`

Answer (score 1):

This let you to set a gesture for double tap on a view.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Remember that a UIButton is a UIView